# Flash memory has been wiped from Zebra GK420d. How do I get the default font(s) back?

Tags: printer

any help is appreciated.  I have a Zebra GK420d where the flash memory was wiped and now I am not able to print.  All labels that are printed are blank.  Does anyone know how to load the default fonts back on the printer?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow the links: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/desktop/gk420d.html

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the reply but I'm not seeing anything there that would help with this situation.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @GuestUser908667 The Link leads to the manual which states: "Graphics, fonts and programming files can be sent to the printer from the Microsoft Windows
operating systems by using the Zebra Setup Utilities (and driver), ZebraNet™ Bridge or
Zebra ® ZDownloader found on the user's CD or at www.zebra.com. "